# Autolayout bottom align issue

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a viewController with a view in it, and I'd like to align it to the bottom of the screen.
Now I have a UIView on the bottom with 0 trailing, 0 leading and 0 bottom space from the container, also I've set up a fix height for that view. In the IB if I change the screen size from 4" to 3,5", then everything is just fine, but on the device I don't see the view at the bottom..

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried not setting a fixed height for the view, but a less or equal height?

Comment: in their any other views or constraints in your viewController's view ?

Comment: Hi, the less or equal doesn't solve my issue.
Yes I have other constraints, but they're not connected to that specific view.

Comment: The constraint name is Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide, shouldn't it be Bottom Space to: SuperView?

Comment: You might have the problem cached on your device. Did you try uninstalling it first before running it on the device again?

Comment: Yes I tried, now my solution is to move the bottom view on viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

You only need 4 constraints for this scenario:

1. leading space to container (from the left edge of subview to left of superview)
2. bottom space to bottom layout guide
3. height constraint
4. width constraint OR a trailing space to container*

*At a meta-level, auto-layout attempts to determine the minimum amount of information needed to size/position a view. If you know that it's 0 from the left and 0 from the right, you don't need to set the width because that can depend on the device orientation. Alternately, if you do constrain the width, then you only need the distance from left OR right to determine the position.

I'd blow away all the existing constraints that might be interfering and then manually set these.

Comment: So the leading and trailing space doesn't set the width of the view?

Comment: Yes and no. If no width constraint is set, then leading and trailing space will automatically resize the view to ensure it stays 0 from left/right. (you may go this way if rotation is important, and in fact, I'll revise now that I think about it). If width constraint is set, then you only need leading, as it could confuse autolayout if width was constant AND it had to be X distance from right side (and you'd receive a warning)